# .p12 file not picking up from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, ssl

I have setup spring boot application which deploys as war in tomcat.So I go to tomcat and do the configuration as below in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate  
                      certificateKeystoreFile="file:///D:/cert/test.p12"
                      certificateKeystorePassword="password"
                      certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12"
                      type="RSA"
                      />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

This works fine,Same configuration I try to do from eclipse.ini but it does not work,The applications complains that keystore and keystore password not found.I am running latest version of Eclipse.Please help

Eclipse.ini

-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="file:///D:/cert/test.p12"

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="password"

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType="pkcs12"

Answer (score 1):

Passed in the arguments to VM Arguments from eclipse.ini in Eclipse it worked fine.